# How is the review count in the 'header' calculated

Tags: bug

My review count, which appears at the top (see image below) shows **805** items need attention, but, when I click on it and see the screen below, the maths doesn't add up! It has been like this for many days now.

[image]

Comment: I believe it's just heavily cached.

Comment: It must be very heavily cached @slhck, that number alters quite often. As soon as I posted the above screen, the number had changed from 805 to 800 (although the maths still didn't add up). I mean, it does (if you hover over the 805) show a tilde  (~) which means 'about' ... Again, thank you for your time/answer

Comment: If you're an active reviewer, that'd explain the discrepancy. I'm pretty sure that posts *still in the queue but handled by you* count towards the top bar, but not for the per-queue numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's a count of **everything everyone needs to review** rather than *what you can review*.

I think this is how it's intended, from [Anna Lear's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#230726) and [shog9's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-much/230802#230802) answers over on meta.stackexchange.

> ... this is everything in review, even stuff that you, personally, can't
>   review. Super-expensive to personalize this - so the alternative is
>   simply not having an indicator ...

As well as the caching...

oh, also here is another discussion about its functionality [Modulate the review notification's color ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230833/modulate-the-review-notifications-color-to-reflect-changes-or-make-it-dismissi)